# Taylor Polynomial of degree 5 centered around x=x

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was wondering if this was possible. For a taylor series polynomial shouldn't it be centered around $x_0$ instead of $x$?

The question was asking for a Taylor polynomial of degree five in the form of $f(x+h,y)$ in $x+h$ centered around $x$, keeping $y$ as a constant, so I wrote something like:

$$f(x+h)\approx\sum_{n=0}^{5}\frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}(x+h)^n$$

But I think it should be something like this:

$$f(x+h)\approx\sum_{n=0}^{5}\frac{f^{(n)}(h)}{n!}(x+h)^n$$

Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: Just a secondary issue: How did $f$ go from being a function of $2$ variables to a function of $1$?

Comment: The question asked to write $f(x+h,y)$ in $x+h$ so I assumed it like that and $y$ is a constant. I'm not sure if that is right though.

Comment: Basically you're just supposed to keep the $y$ around without doing anything to it.

Comment: Oh, righto. I'll keep that in mind, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to treat $x+h$ as a variable.  Let's let $z=x+h$. Now

$$f(z,y)\approx\sum_{n=0}^5\frac{f^{(n)}(x,y)}{n!}(z-x)^n=\sum_{n=0}^5\frac{f^{(n)}(x,y)}{n!}h^n.$$

The last expression comes from substituting $x+h$ for $z$.

Comment: I believe I've fixed it.  Although it would help if you said what the mistake was.

Comment: come on $f(z)\approx\sum_{n=0}^5\frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}(z-x)^n$

Comment: quite important, isn't it

Comment: I didn't say that it wasn't important.  I just wasn't seeing what my mistake was at first.

Comment: you weren't seing OP's mistake neither